# PHP Floor() Function with incorrect values

Tags: php, function, integer, rounding, floor

yesterday I found some issue in my code, but I don't understand what wrong is with PHP Floor function. For some values Floor() is not rounding correctly integer values.

```
$prise = 550.05 * 100;
echo $prise;                    // 55005

echo "\nFloor: ";
echo floor(intval($prise));
echo " - ";
echo floor((int)($prise));
echo " - ";
echo floor($prise);
echo " - ";
echo floor(55005);              // Floor: 55004 - 55004 - 55004 - 55005

echo "\nNumber format: ";
echo number_format($prise, 0, '.', '');    // Number format: 55005
```

As you can see, correct value should equal 55005. For unknown reasons, the function still rounds the not decimal value.
Could someone explain to me how it works, or is it a PHP issue?

Example in online PHP sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55b1782e1f3799815d610777a3de1c2d297e24c8

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no point in calling `floor()` after you've already converted the argument to an integer.

Comment: `550.05` can't be represented exactly in floating point, the approximation is something like `550.0499999999`. Multiplying by 100 produces `55004.99999999`, so floor is `55004`. It's best to use `round()` instead of `floor()` so it doesn't matter whether the approximation is high or low.